# Publishing to MediaWiki from MS Word

Tags: ms-word, mediawiki

I have inherited a project that intends to make an internal MediaWiki site the multimedia, search, and archiving repository for documents originally authored in Microsoft Word. Today, those Word documents are converted into PDF, and then stored on a file server.  But they are not directly searchable, they have proven difficult to update, and the existing file server itself is difficult to integrate with other internal applications that might want to consume & expose the content in those PDFs.  Plus this is 2023, not 2003.  Enter MediaWiki.

I am sorting through the options that allow the content producers to stick with their existing content production process.  They like Word.  They are used to it, it's an approved company software, there is training on how to use Word effectively.  It handles embedding of multimedia.
Some use it on Windows, and some on MacOS.

Where I'm stuck is how to bolt on something to the end of their process so that the content can be authored in Word, but also sends a WYSIWYG version to the MediaWiki.  This would need to happen for both authoring new content (a new page), and editing existing content.  Create/edit in word --> publish to wiki.  Lather/rinse/repeat.

The [Word macros described on the MediaWiki page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word_Macros) are simply about converting into the MW markdown.  Totally useful and a necessary part of the solution, but only half the problem.  The converted doc still has to get published.

I tried using [Open Office as a middle layer with Sun's Wiki Publisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:WordToWiki#OpenOffice_or_LibreOffice).  But: A) that involves two extra pieces of software to get approved & installed (OO + extension & a Java runtime); and B) I think the latest (2008!?) version of the extension is no longer compatible with the current versions of Open Office.

The [MS add-in for MediaWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:WordToWiki#Microsoft_Office_Word_Add-in_For_MediaWiki) sounds flaky, and I've read only works for Windows install.

Doing the [copy/paste method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:WordToWiki#VisualEditor_2) sounds the least terrible idea, but is still pretty terrible for documents that can be very media-rich.  And looooooong.

Has anyone successfully implemented frictionless publishing from Word to a MediaWiki?  I'd love to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Short version..
Word documents are saved in certain folder on the companies server. A script copies them to where the MediaWiki server is together with an XML file with the Meta data describing the files. There an import script that runs every minute, unless its already running, will pick up the xml and process all the word documents. Logs everything to Graylog and moves document to success or error folders when done. Conversion is done with Pandoc.
Daily around 20-50 documents are processed and it started with 200,000+ for older documents.
Long version, I think a chat would be better.

Comment: I think I follow, thank you for outlining the critical steps.  I hadn't considered an agent sniffing for new files on a schedule.  I need to discuss that with the authors to see if a slight delay (based on the agent schedule) is a sticking point.  I also appreciate your providing the size of your corpus as a helpful reference.